# codeigniter - hide variable from url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to do something very simple in codeigniter. I have a view, which contains several person profiles. Each person profile has contact button and it should go to a contact form which sends an email to the chosen person. So I have tried something like this:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/ci.php/controller/contact/<?= $email ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Contact</a>
```

And this is OK, but I do not want the email to be visible in the URL. Is this possible ?

Comment: You don't want the URL to show the email address, but yet you've constructed the URL to contain the email address.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want data to be visible in the URL you should not use GET. Instead take a look at the POST method. But if the problem is that you don't want to show just the e-mail, maybe you could pass an user id (or other variable that is unique for each user) in the URL, and use it to fetch the e-mail on the contact page.

(Please note that just because the POST data is not immediately visible in the URL field, it is not completely invisible. POST data can be easily displayed in different debugging tools.)

Comment: If the OP is using CodeIgniter, then he's already using `POST`.

Comment: While it may not be in the URL, POST data can still be viewed in browser's debugging tools.

Comment: Good point Rocket Hazmat, I've added the information in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use an array inside your controller:

```
$emails = array(0=>'email1@website.com', 1=>'..', 2=>'');
```

Your link would be

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/ci.php/controller/contact/<?= $email_index ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Contact</a>
```

And then do something like this: `email_to($emails[$email_index])`

Well, you get the ideea.